# People who extract raw materials

Tags: meaning, american-english, biology

People who extract raw materials from the ground are called what

Comment: Which raw materials are you talking about?

Comment: _Grounders_, or perhaps _grinders_.

Comment: This is a really interesting question that could be improved with some examples. For instance, are the raw materials ores, metals, sand, stone, fossil fuels? Do they dig holes in the ground or primarily work from the surface?

Comment: Farmers too, including raw materials like jute and flax.

Answer (score 1):

[**Miners**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miner)

The link gives the relevant definition of the verb “mine” from which this is derived:

> to get (something, such as ore) from the earth

This is not to be confused with [*minors*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minor), who would be too young for this sort of employment.

Here is a [literary example](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=my+darling+clementine+lyrics&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) of its usage:

> In a cavern, in a canyon
> Excavating for a mine
> Dwelt a miner forty-niner
> And his daughter, Clementine

For the non-native speaker, a study of this example may expand his appreciation of the history and mating habits of West-coast Americans.